# Screen locking just after sign in

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, display, system

I really like Elementary OS so I tried to install Loki on my laptop.  It is a Lenovo Y570.  Here are specs: https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-ideapad-y570/specs/

Video is NVIDIA GeForce GT 555M / Intel HD Graphics 3000 - 1 GB

.  First of all, I had a lot of trouble installing it.  I was getting a black screen before the login screen with the live disk but I found the nomodeset trick for nvidia cards.  Still the screen was messing up (possibly when locking) during the install process that way, but I was able to install without any issues using the straight install partition with the nomodeset option.

Now I have an OS that boots, but the login screen is funny.  My user name is there but there is no user name on what should be the guest account login.  The login screen will accept my password but once entering it the login fields disappear but nothing else happens.  There is no touchpad or keyboard response at this point, so I can't even flip to a text session and do anything.

Freya worked fine for me.  I install it with the live image and there aren't any issues.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The guest session won't show any name unless you select it. 

Can you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 instead of login?

Comment: You are right about the guest session.  Yes, I can access the text console with Ctrl+Alt+F1 before signing in.  When I switched to the tty screen from the login screen I got a bunch of error messages and now this screen appears locked as well.  Here are some of the error messages:

Comment: When I switched to the tty screen from the login screen I got a bunch of error messages and now this screen appears locked as well.  Here are some of the error messages:  'Restarting adapter queue is full'  'Error sending REPLY_LEDS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -28' MANY OF THESE:  'usb 2-1-port1: cannot reset (err = -110)  'Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?'  And it ends with this repeatedly:  'NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s!  [systemd-timesyn:717]

Comment: Please note that I didn't have anything plugged into USB at the time but for the flash drive I just installed Loki from.

Comment: It looks like it is a long ongoing Ubuntu bug, since back to 15.10: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1530405  If anyone has anything helpful to recommend then please do.  I guess Ubuntu is not my friend any more nor is anything based on it.  :-(

Answer (score 1):

The guest session won't show any name unless you select it.

About the rest, It seems that the bug is related to your graphics card. You need to install the correct driver. Go into any tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1 - F6</kbd>) and log in. First, update your system:

```
 sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Then do (just one of the following lines):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-prime nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

or if you prefer the latest stable driver:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-prime nvidia-367 nvidia-settings
```

Comment: How do I install the driver?  The OS locks up 30 seconds after booting to the login screen no matter what I do.

Comment: can you add to the grub options at boot `acpi=off ` ?? You can edit a boot entry pressing F2 when the grub menu appears. If you are not sure where to put this, look for `quiet splash` and put it in the middle. Then boot and try again.

Comment: Also from the bug you have mentioned earlier, some say disabling USB 3 from the bios/firmware could also do the trick.

Comment: I understand how to edit grub options, but what will acpi=off do for me?  I will try it and report back if I see anything different happen.

Comment: Hey thanks!  acpi=off worked.  I am just doing updates now and I will install the drivers.  Knowing those is a great help as well because it's always hard to get current information on where they are at with nvidia drivers.

Comment: nvidia-367 booted to a black screen but nvidia-current worked great.  Thanks all!

Comment: Glad it worked. I think now you can remove `nomodeset` and `acpi=off` from the grub options. Also, if you want to use the nvidia card open nvidia settings and change it. With `nvidia-prime` you can only use one card at a time.

Comment: Yeah I did not persist nomodeset and acpi=off anyway and yes it does work without now that the drivers are installed.  To anyone coming here after... The grub menu is the one that pops up during boot.  It will give several options, the main one being 'elementary'.  To edit the grub option, with the 'elementary' option press 'e' to edit the command that it will start the kernel with.  Scroll down to the line linux which will have a command with a bunch of parameters containing 'quiet splash'.  Edit as explained above and hit F10 to boot with it.

Comment: Ok I spoke too soon.  I went into nvidia-settings and it would not allow me to select the other graphics card.  I just got an empty error dialog with a red exclaimation point.  So I am only on the low power card.  Since then I have tried nvidia-340, nvidia-367 and the proprietary driver installed and they only boot to black screen even with nomodeset.  So it seems the best I can get right now is nvidia-common with only the base intel card.  Please make any more suggestions that might be helpful, I am at wits end at this point.  Now I don't even have the option to switch cards in prime.

Comment: Disable secureboot in the firmware.